# Deploying ASP.NET MVC5 to IIS10 using public ip from local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, web-publishing

As stated in title I would like to publish my asp.net mvc5 application from my home network using IIS 10 so it can be accessed using my public ip.

Comment: When you say `my public ip`, it's not the IP of your computer but it's the iP of your internet provider. If you can publish application directly from your computer by making your personal IP as public all the hosting providers will go bankrupt. You actually can not do this. You can host your application on your computer and make it available inside the network which you are connected to. but outside the network, you can't do that.

Comment: When I said public ip I meant IP which is provided to me by my internet provider. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: I got that... even with that it won't be that straight forward. Problem of DNS resolution by IP, DomainName mapping, if you have multiple devices connected in your home network routing traffic to particular computer where the application is running and lot other. I am not a network expert but by looking at the simple logic of web hosting, I think this won't be possible just like that...

Comment: I would just want to be able to access to my page using something like 77.77.77.77:4000